# How to programmatically dim screen in UWP app

Tags: c#, windows, uwp

I'm trying to find way how to programmatically dim screen in the UWP app, but I can't find any related API... is there anything like that?

Comment: As far as i know there is no API that allows you to control the brightness of the screen in the UWP platform. Reason behind this is because it is a system task that the OS has to handle. IF you want to do this, you can change the colors of the items on your View to become darker a bit which will emulate reducing brightness, same as the cinema mode buttons on some websites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**

This is possible since **Windows 10 Creators Update**, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.graphics.display.brightnessoverride.

---

Unfortunately, there is no such API that can control the screen brightness in Universal Windows Platform (UWP). As @Rafael said, the screen brightness is thought to be a global setting controlled by the System Settings. And in some device families such as IoT, the device even may has no monitor.

If you want to dim the screen in your app, you can try to add a dark overlay on top of your view and control its opacity. Also, you are welcome to vote on [**UserVoice**](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform/suggestions/2359006-api-to-control-screen-brightness) to ask for this feature.

Comment: Is this still the case for now?

Comment: @PaulKaram For the latest news, please check on [UserVoice](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform/suggestions/2359006-api-to-control-screen-brightness). And according to Clint Rutkas [MSFT], in the upcoming Windows 10 Creators update, we have this ability.

Comment: This is not the case anymore, please see the answer below.

Answer (score 3):

In newer versions of UWP API this is possible, please see:
[UWP > API reference > Windows.Graphics.Display > BrightnessOverride](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.graphics.display.brightnessoverride)

### Windows 10 requirements:

**Device family**
Windows 10 Creators Update (introduced v10.0.15063.0)
**API contract**
Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract (introduced v4)